# Htaccess - url redirection issue in drupal

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite the url as below.

```
old url : wwwdev.xxx.com/x/y/z=abc

new url : www.xxx.com/folder/x/y/z=abc
```

present I am using the below script. Redirection working fine.but not getting the query string and folder.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wwwdev.xxx.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.xxx.com.au/folder/ [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:wwwdev\.)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1/folder%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it is not working for me. I tested in sample file in core php. my htaccess file contains the above code only.

Comment: Ravi, Its working fine now. previously i was  placed the code in different node in my htaccess. Thanks for your support